# Tableau server installation

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to implement tableau server installation on a Ubuntu machine(AWS) as a multi-node cluster, 
Whenever I try to add a backgrounder process to the worker node , the node status changes to degraded . If I remove the backgrounder process then the node status changes back to running. There are no apt errors except the last job step failed due to time out.

Also on the tableau ui status page - i see that backgrounder for the node is unlicensed. Has anyone faced similar issues? How should I solve it?

I am using a trial version.

Server details
Tableau-server = 10.5
build: 10500.18.0109.1050

```
ubuntu@10:~$ tsm pending-changes apply
This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?
(y/n): y
Starting deployments asynchronous job.
7% - Retrieving the topology to deploy.
15% - Retrieving the configuration to deploy.
23% - Validating the new topology.
30% - Determining if server needs to be started.
38% - Disabling all services.
46% - Waiting for the services to stop.
53% - Updating nodes to new topology.
61% - Waiting for topology to be applied.
69% - Updating nodes to new configuration.
76% - Reconfiguring services.
84% - Waiting for services to reconfigure and start.
92% - Enabling all services.
100% - The services failed to start.
The deployments job has failed.
See '/home/ubuntu/.tableau/tsm/tsm.log' for more information.
```

logs : /home/ubuntu/.tableau/tsm/tsm.log

```
2018-08-07 19:22:33 main : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.ServerApi - Client request: GET https://10.100.52.45:8850/api/0.5/asyncJobs/3
2018-08-07 19:22:33 main : INFO  com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.async.AsyncJobDelegate - Retrieved async job status Failed. Id=3, progress=100
2018-08-07 19:22:33 main : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.async.AsyncJobDelegate - Asynchronous job 3 completed but wasn't successful.
2018-08-07 19:22:33 main : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.Tabadmin - The deployments job has failed.

ubuntu@10:~$ tsm status -v
node1: 10.100.52.45
        Status: RUNNING
        'Tableau Server Gateway 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Application Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server VizQL Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Cache Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Coordination Service 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Cluster Controller 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Search And Browse 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Backgrounder 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Data Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Data Engine 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server File Store 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Repository 0' is running (Active Repository).
        'Tableau Server Administration Agent 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Administration Controller 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Service Manager 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server License Manager 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Database Maintenance 0' is stopped.
        'Tableau Server Backup/Restore 0' is stopped.
        'Tableau Server Site Import/Export 0' is stopped.
        'Tableau Server SAML Service 0' is stopped.
node2: 10.100.52.245
        Status: DEGRADED
        'Tableau Server Gateway 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Cluster Controller 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Backgrounder 0' is in an error state.
        'Tableau Server Backgrounder 1' is in an error state.
        'Tableau Server Data Engine 0' is in an error state.
        'Tableau Server Administration Agent 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Service Manager 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Database Maintenance 0' is stopped.
        'Tableau Server Backup/Restore 0' is stopped.
        'Tableau Server Site Import/Export 0' is stopped.

ubuntu@10:~$ tsm jobs list
ID: 1
        Type: DeploymentsJob
        Status message: This job completed successfully.
        Created at: 8/7/18 6:11 PM
        Completed at: 8/7/18 6:12 PM
ID: 2
        Type: InitializeServerJob
        Status message: This job completed successfully.
        Created at: 8/7/18 6:12 PM
        Completed at: 8/7/18 6:21 PM
ID: 3
        Type: DeploymentsJob
        Status message: This job timed out after '1500' seconds.
        Created at: 8/7/18 6:57 PM
        Completed at: 8/7/18 7:22 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this but the issues is likely that a trial isn't licenced for a multi-node install. 
For your POC trial just run as a single node (that will be plenty of grunt for 10-25 users) and if you need more than that talk to your Tableau rep